# Why can I not mutably borrow separate fields from a mutex guard?

Tags: rust, mutex, borrow-checker

Trying to get mutable references to separate fields through a `MutexGuard`:

```
struct MyObject {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i32,
}

fn func_1(mtx: &Mutex<MyObject>) {
    let mut obj = mtx.lock().unwrap();
    let a = &mut obj.a;
    let b = &mut obj.b;

    *a += 1;
    *b *= 2;
}
```

results in an error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `obj` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:11:18
   |
10 |     let a = &mut obj.a;
   |                  --- first mutable borrow occurs here
11 |     let b = &mut obj.b;
   |                  ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
12 |     
13 |     *a += 1;
   |     ------- first borrow later used here
```

This has me a bit confused. This works when `obj` is a simple mutable reference (`&mut MyObject`). I thought maybe the `Deref` trait was the one causing the problem, but it also works if `obj` is a `&mut Box<MyObject>`.

See it on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=350089f3b3ce4574f90cb1c4d2db5a24).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

Mutex::lock returns a RAII lock guard in addition of ways to deal with its contained value. To get its contained value as `&mut` (and subsequently "split borrow"), you need to:

- save the guard (returned by `lock`) in a separate value, as the lock needs to live as long as the value is accessed.
- extract the value as `&mut` from the guard with `MutexGuard::deref_mut`.

Here's an updated `func_1`:

```
use std::ops::DerefMut;

fn func_1(mtx: &Mutex<MyObject>) {
    let mut guard = mtx.lock().unwrap();
    let obj = guard.deref_mut();
    let a = &mut obj.a;
    let b = &mut obj.b;

    *a += 1;
    *b *= 2;
}
```

Comment: I had found workarounds like this, but the purpose of my question is why. Why does it work for `Box` but not for `MutexGuard`?

Comment: I guess it's because Box' implementation of deref_mut is a simple Rust deref, whileas MutexGuard's does a function call in between which makes it impossible for the compiler to see that it's accessing the same object (which would allow a split borrow). But I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm going to ask a separate question since it seems that `Box` is the outlier not `MutexGuard`,cuz it also fails for `RefMut`. You might be right in your reasoning though.