# Mutable borrow fail in Mutex

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I get an error about mutable borrow fail in Mutex.

Here is the code.
It's Ok now. But it will fail to compile if uncommenting the 2 lines, which wraps the `state` into a Mutex and unwraps it out.

Why does the Mutex make the difference?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct State {
    h1: HashMap<String, String>,
    h2: HashMap<String, String>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = State {
        h1: HashMap::new(),
        h2: HashMap::new(),
    };

    // It fails to compile if uncommenting these 2 lines!
    //let state = Mutex::new(state);
    //let mut state = state.lock().unwrap();

    let v1 = state.h1.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
    let v2 = state.h2.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
    v1.push_str("123");
    v2.push_str("123");
}
```

The error if uncommenting the 2 lines:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `state` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> tmp.rs:20:14
   |
19 |     let v1 = state.h1.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
   |              ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
20 |     let v2 = state.h2.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
   |              ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
21 |     v1.push_str("123");
   |     -- first borrow later used here
```

===EDIT===

It's Ok if changing some code order:

```
    let state = Mutex::new(state);
    let mut state = state.lock().unwrap();

    let v1 = state.h1.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
    v1.push_str("123");
    let v2 = state.h2.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
    v2.push_str("123");
```

It seems that `v1` holds a reference of `state`. If `v1` ends, it drops the reference, and then `state` can be borrowed again.

Why `v1` holds the reference of `state`?

====EDIT====

@Alexey Larionov gave the answer. And I find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60253791/why-can-i-not-mutably-borrow-separate-fields-from-a-mutex-guard). And I should get the `state` out of the MutexGuard manually by `deref_mut()`. So adding this line makes things ok:

```
    let state = state.deref_mut();
```

Comment: if you are brave (or reckless!) enough you can implement *borrow splitting*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68581212/2588800. Otherwise you can do what @Netwave has suggested or use "interior mutability"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate @Netwave's answer a bit more, in case without a `Mutex` you don't get such an error, because by doing this

```
let mut state = State {
        h1: HashMap::new(),
        h2: HashMap::new(),
};
let v1 = state.h1.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
let v2 = state.h2.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
```

`v1` mutably borrows `state.h1`, and `v2` mutably borrows `state.h2`, and both of them count as immutable borrows of `state` in order to prevent moving the `state` out (e.g. `let state2 = state;` while other borrows exist). Since all the rules of borrowing are satisfied (*either* at most one mutable borrow per object *or* as many immutable borrows per object), borrowing is permitted.

In the `Mutex` case this line

```
let mut state = state.lock().unwrap();
```

makes the `state` of type `MutexGuard::<State>`. By using it in this way

```
let v1 = state.h1.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
```

Rust won't find `h1` in `MutexGuard::<State>`, that's why it will use `DerefMut` trait to get `&mut State` implicitly from it. That's where you mutably borrow `state`. Since you later use the similar construction for `v2` , you'll try to obtain a second mutable borrow on `state`, thus receiving the error

Comment: Thanks very much. I can not do as @Netwave suggests, because I have to get v1 and v2 first (to make sure the key exist), and then update them both. Is there other method let me handle the `Mutex<state>` just like `state`?

Comment: Maybe just `if (state.h1.contains_key("abc") && state.h2.contains_key("abc")) { /* Netwave's solution */}`. The `if` condition should borrow `state` immutably

Answer (score 1):

By doing that you take 2 mutable references to the state itself. To solve it you could rescope one of the get_mut calls:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut state = State {
        h1: HashMap::new(),
        h2: HashMap::new(),
    };

    // It fails to compile if uncommenting these 2 lines!
    let state = Mutex::new(state);
    let mut state = state.lock().unwrap();

    {
        let v1 = state.h1.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
        v1.push_str("123");
    }

    let v2 = state.h2.get_mut("abc").unwrap();
    v2.push_str("123");
}
```

That way, by the time you get the second reference, the first one is dropped already.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=595009bd4e0f643ba5c91a24d7268b6e)

Comment: Thanks. It's ok even without the `{}` block. I append some code at the original question. But I still want to know the reason.